# Counting the number of times a word appears in n tweets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of about 118,000 tweets. Here's a made up sample:

```
Tweets
1 The apple is red
2 The grape is purple
3 The tree is green
```

I have also used the 'set' function to arrive at a list of of every unique word that is found in my data frame of tweets. For the example above it looks like this (in no particular order):

```
Words
1 The
2 is
3 apple
4 grape 
....so on
```

Basically I need to find out how many tweets contain a given word. For example, "The" is found in 3 tweets, "apple" is found in 1 tweet, "is" is found in 3 tweets, and so on.

I have tried using a nested for loop that looks like:

```
number_words = [0]*len(words)
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(len(tweets)):
        if words[i] in tweets[j]:
            number_words[i] += 1
number_words
```

Which creates a new list and counts the amount of tweets that contain the given word, for each word down the list. However I have found that this incredibly inefficient, the code block takes forever to run.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: dataframe pandas?

Comment: yes dataframe pandas

Comment: You could use [sklearn's CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use: [str.count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html)

```
df.Tweets.str.count(word).sum()
```

for example, i suppose words is the list

```
for word in Words:
    print(f'{word} count: {df.Tweets.str.count(word).sum()}')
```

full sample:

```
import pandas as pd
data = """    
Tweets
The apple is red
The grape is purple
The tree is green 
"""
datb = """    
Words
The
is
apple
grape 
    """

dfa = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=';')
dfb = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(datb), sep=';')

Words = dfb['Words'].values
dico = {}
for word in Words:
    dico[word] = dfa.Tweets.str.count(word).sum()

print(dico)
```

output:

```
{'The': 3, 'is': 3, 'apple': 1, 'grape ': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a default dictionary for this to store all word counts like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_counts = defaultdict(int)
for tweet in tweets:
    for word in tweet:
        word_counts[word] += 1
# print(word_counts['some_word']) will output occurrence of some_word
```

Answer (score 1):

This will take your list of words and turn it into a dictionary

```py
 import collections

 words = tweets.split()
 counter = collections.Counter(words)

 for key , value in sorted(counter.items()):
      print("`{}` is repeated {} time".format(key , value))
```